# VBA code to copy parts of a column in to rows

Tags: vba, excel

I'm really new to VBA and need some assistance in copying data from one single column, with evenly spaced partitions between data in the same column and pasted as rows.

I have an excel sheet with 300 business cards and are placed as in image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pztF.jpg).

Each business card is one highlighted block as in this example:

[image: picture]

I need a VBA code to copy the data in column C and place as rows under the headers A,B,C,D,E,F.

Is there a VBA code that can do such a thing?

Any help is very much appreciated!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This site is not a script writing site for people to ask for code and then have other develop it for them. Having said that, it is your first post so I have answered your question. Try coming up with some code through using the Macro recorder in Excel and then asking a question pertaining to how you can get it working properly. Enjoy your time here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
 Option Explicit
 Sub TransposeBusinessCardData()

      Dim BusinessCardDataSheet As Worksheet
      'Replace BusinessCardSheet with the sheet name of your sheet
      Set BusinessCardDataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BusinessCardSheet")
      Dim ResultSheet As Worksheet
      'Replace ResultSheet with the sheet name of the sheet you want to paste the data in
      Set ResultSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ResultSheet")

      Dim LastRow As Long
      LastRow = BusinessCardDataSheet.Cells(BusinessCardDataSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

      Dim RowReference As Long
      Dim BusinessCardData As Range
      Dim ResultRowRef As Long

      'To paste from Row 2 on the ResultSheet
      ResultRowRef = 2

      'Step 7 Because there is 7 Rows between the start of each Business card
      For RowReference = 2 To LastRow Step 7

           BusinessCardDataSheet.Activate
           Set BusinessCardData = BusinessCardDataSheet.Range(Cells(RowReference, "C"), Cells(RowReference + 5, "C"))
           BusinessCardData.Copy

           ResultSheet.Cells(ResultRowRef, "B").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
                                                                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                                                    Transpose:=True
           ResultRowRef = ResultRowRef + 1

      Next RowReference


 End Sub
```